# Photo Stream issue with iCloud

Tags: ios, photo-stream

I have been noticing some Photo Stream issues with my 3 devices; iPad 2, iPhone 5, and iPhone 4. The problem is that pictures taken with the iPhone 4 will not populate to the other 2 devices, and vice versa.

The only difference that I see is that the iPad and iPhone 5 are logged into the same iCloud account (mine), but the iPhone 4 is logged into my wife's iCloud account.

Could this be the source of the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. **Photostream** shares photos between devices logged into a single iCloud account. You can post photos to a **Shared Photostream** and designated parties will be notified, but the photos aren't downloaded to computers or iDevices.